Flexbox: Position element next to group of centered elements without the group adjusting position
I am trying to center with Flexbox a group of elements  (all elements except the "Reset" button) in a div. Then I want to add the Reset button right next to this centered group of elements in the same line, but without the group to adjust their position with Flexbox. So basically the group is centered but the reset button is right next to those elements. I am looking for a efficient and most importantly simple solution, not for "hard coding" the position manually.
Code:


.flexbox-div {
  /* grid-column: span 3; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

#main-modal-reset-btn-style {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flexbox-div">
      <span>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="modal-filter-repeat-id"
          name="main-modal-filter-repeat"
        />
        <label for="modal-filter-repeat-id"> Only Repeat</label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <select name="main-modal-categories">
          <option value="allcategories">All categories</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="difficulty-all-modal"
          name="difficultymodal"
          value="all"
          checked="checked"
        />
        <label for="difficulty-all-modal"> All</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="difficulty-easy-modal"
          name="difficultymodal"
          value="easy"
        />
        <label for="difficulty-easy-modal">Easy</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="difficulty-medium-modal"
          name="difficultymodal"
          value="medium"
        />
        <label for="difficulty-medium-modal"> Medium</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="difficulty-modal-hard"
          name="difficultymodal"
          value="hard"
        />
        <label for="difficulty-modal-hard">Hard</label>
      </span>
      <button class="main-modal-reset-filter" id="main-modal-reset-btn-style">
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



Thanks

If you want the resent button at right, you just have to remove position absolute from that button. Not sure it is the same you're asking for.
